# Alternatives to ScriptApp scope usage in GMail Add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I'm trying to publish a GMail Add-on with a scheduler functionality and using the Google Apps Script's built in trigger functions to achieve the goal. However when I try to deploy the add-on I get the below error message.

```
Gmail add-ons may not request the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp scope.
```

[image]

Is this the intended behaviour? Are there any workarounds to achieve the same without using trigger?

Without the scheduler the add-on would be pretty much useless...

Comment: Gmail add-ons are not really meant to activate beyond when the user has selected an email. They may change in the future, but for now that is what Gmail addons are used for. You can deploy a regular gsuite add on and still access Gmail services.

Comment: Thanks for the insight tehhowch! Had been trying to crack this without success...